# Can I use the different settings sections over different pages using the save options group?

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api

I registered one options group with few different options sections. Each section is meant for different page.

```
register_setting(                       // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting
        'mhp_options',                  // Options group
        'mhp_plugin_options',           // Database option
        'mhp_plugin_options_validate'   // The sanitization callback,
);

// Manage Menu section
add_settings_section(                   // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section
        $mhp_manage_menu_section,   // Unique identifier for the settings section
        __('Manage Menu Settings', 'mhp'),  // Section title
        '__return_false',               // Section callback (we don't want anything)
        $mhp_manage_menu_section            // Menu slug
);
add_settings_section(                   
        $mhp_home_page_layout_settings_section,     
        __('Home Page Layout Settings', 'mhp'),     
        '__return_false',               
        $mhp_home_page_layout_settings_section          
);
```

Then each page is using

```
settings_fields( 'mhp_options' ); 
do_settings_sections( $mhp_manage_menu_section);
```

so the other page is using

```
settings_fields( 'mhp_options' ); 
do_settings_sections( $mhp_home_page_layout_settings_section);
```

but it looks like on save only current section is saved in the options table. What ever was already there is deleted.

Do I have to create new options group for each page or is there any other solution?

Comment: If you can retrieve all the fields names from outside settings api (e.g. you have saved it in a static class variable or in a global variable) what you ask is possible and easy. Just for clarification for 'field names' I mean the ids you pass as first argument to `add_settings_field` for fields of all sections.

Comment: I already found the solution. Before posting it I wanted to give opportunity someone to earn the points. Your way would work, do you want to create an answer out of it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to merge existing options before saving options in case not all options are presented on the page we are about save.

So in the end of `$sanitize_callback` in [register_setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) function just before I return the data I call below function where $existing are all existing options saved in database.

```
function merge_options( $existing,  $input ) { // Merges existing options with $input to preserve existing options

    if ( !is_array( $existing ) || !is_array( $input ) ) // something went wrong
        return $data;
    return array_merge( $existing, $input );
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `$input` refers to the `$options` parameter received in the `sanitize_callback`, and `$existing` refers to the option that you can retrieve with `get_option( $option_name )`

Answer (score 1):

To complement @Radek's answer, here is another way to use his solution.

```
public function sanitize_callback ( $options )
{
    $saved_options = $this->get_option( 'your_option_name' );
    $options = $this->sanitize_options( $options );

    if ( is_array( $saved_options ) && is_array( $options ) )
    {
        $options = array_merge( $saved_options, $options );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

The `sanitize_callback` function is the one passed as an argument in your `register_setting`, and then you can use another one (named `sanitize_options` in my case) to do your sanitization.

This `sanitize_callback` will take care of merging all the options under the same `$option_name`.